# How do I turn the multiple-line form of conditions to postfix form?

Tags: ruby, postfix-notation

This is a multiple-line form of conditional statement:

```
if button_down?(@buttons[:forward]) and @speed < @max_speed
  @speed += @acceleration 
elsif button_down?(@buttons[:backward]) and @speed > -@max_speed
  @speed -= @acceleration
end
```

I want to convert it into a postfix form this:

```
@speed += @acceleration if button_down?(@buttons[:forward]) and @speed < @max_speed
@speed -= @acceleration elsif button_down?(@button[:backward]) and @speed > -@max_speed
```

The code above raises:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif, expecting end-of-input
```

How can this be made in a correct way? Going with `if` always?

Comment: There is no postfix form for `elsif`. It there were any, if would not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt I understand what are you calling “efficient,” but in this particular case I would go with:

```
@speed +=
  case
  when button_down?(...) then @acceleration 
  when button_down?(...) then -@acceleration
  else 0
  end
```

or even:

```
@speed += @acceleration *
  case
  when button_down?(...) then 1
  when button_down?(...) then -1
  else 0
  end
```

Comment: Well, it isn't particularly efficient. It's just cleaner and I like it lol.

Comment: Please define “efficient.”

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a case statement together with a helper method to DRY the code.

```
@speed +=
case
when satisfy?(:forward, @speed)   then @acceleration
when satisfy?(:backward, -@speed) then -@acceleration
else 0
end

def satisfy?(direction, speed)
  button_down?(direction) && speed < @max_speed
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably extract some of the logic into separate methods:

```
def increase_speed
  @speed = [@max_speed, @speed + @acceleration].min
end

def decrease_speed
  @speed = [-@max_speed, @speed - @acceleration].max
end
```

With these methods you can write something like this:

```
increase_speed if button_down?(@buttons[:forward])
decrease_speed if button_down?(@buttons[:backward])
```

Comment: This looks promising!